# sqlreader reading wrong column

Tags: c#, sql

Im trying to get the unique id from my persons table but the reader keeps trying getting the FirstName column and trying to convert that instead. at least thats what i think is happening

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM Persons WHERE FirstName = " + txtBoxFirst.Text.ToString() + " AND LastName = " + txtBoxLast.Text.ToString()
                                                       , sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader read = dataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                pID = (Int32.Parse(read["ID"].ToString()));
            }
            read.Close();
            sqlConnection.Close();
```

The error shows as

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:**'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'First' to data type int.'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hos does you Persons table look like?

Comment: What is present in the txtBoxFirst.Text ?, Could you enclose it with single quote ?
WHERE FirstName = '" + txtBoxFirst.Text.ToString() + " '

Comment: @miechooy i added a picture of how it looks

Comment: Never construct an SQL statement using user input, otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: @SatishPai enclose what in single quotes? i tried changing the double quotes into single and it says too many characters are literal. and weirdly enough the name in the textbox isnt what its trying to convery. i.e I type in Student, it will still try to convert admin

Comment: Your `ID` field seems to be `varchar` - and you store numbers along with text there.

Comment: dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM Persons WHERE FirstName =' " + txtBoxFirst.Text.ToString() + "' AND LastName = '" + txtBoxLast.Text.ToString()+"'"
                                                       , sqlConnection); When you provide the sql varachar value you need to enclose the data in single quote. @XiaoNingEr

Comment: @SatishPai A yes that was it. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you miss the `'` single-quote in your query so your parameter willn't be a string.

so it might be like

```
"SELECT ID FROM Persons WHERE FirstName = '" + txtBoxFirst.Text.ToString() + "' AND LastName = '" + txtBoxLast.Text.ToString() + "'"
```

But There is a big issue than it is [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

I would suggest you use parameters instead of connected SQL statement string.

make sure your parameter data type size as same as your table schema.

```
string sqlQuery =  "SELECT ID FROM Persons WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName";
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = txtBoxFirst.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtBoxLast.Text;

    SqlDataReader read = dataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        pID = (Int32.Parse(read["ID"].ToString()));
    }
}
```